# limit of probability measures, not quite Vitali-Hahn-Saks

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

probabliy doesnt work, but i try:

It is known, that for a sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ in $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ with pointwise existing limit
$\mu A = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu_n A$ for $A\in\mathcal{A}$, the limiting set function $\mu$ is also a probability measure.

Now let again $\mu_n$ be probability measures and assume that $\mu$ is also a probability measure, but the convergence
$\mu A = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu_n A$ is only true for sets $A$ in a subsystem $\mathcal{E}\subset \mathcal{A}$, which generates $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. $\sigma\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{A}$, and which is closed under finite intersections.

Can one deduce $\mu A = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu_n A$ for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ ?

Or, if one uses a monotone class argument, is it true, that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_n A_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu A_i$ for all $A_i\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu A_i = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu_n A_i$ ?